# Construct incorrect URLs in java with java.net.URL?

Tags: java, url, java-8, construction

Using oracle java 1.8.0_25

I have the following construct

```
URL url = new URL(new URL(new URL("http://localhost:4567/"), "123"), "asd")
```

According the documentation in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/creatingUrls.html
it should produce the URL of `http://localhost:4567/123/asd`
But it produces `http://localhost:4567/asd`

The documentation states

> This code snippet uses the URL constructor that lets you create a URL object from another URL object (the base) and a relative URL specification. The general form of this constructor is:
>
> `URL(URL baseURL, String relativeURL)`
> The first argument is a URL object that specifies the base of the new URL. The second argument is a String that specifies the rest of the resource name relative to the base. If baseURL is null, then this constructor treats relativeURL like an absolute URL specification. Conversely, if relativeURL is an absolute URL specification, then the constructor ignores baseURL.

Is this the correct behavior here?

Comment: According to the documentation: `URL url = new URL("http", "localhost", 4567, "123/asd")` ?

Comment: Question is edited with the addition of quoted text from docs. There are examples also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading the documentation using this constructor:

```
URL(URL baseURL, String relativeURL)
```

So you can do something like this:

```
URL baseUrl = new URL("http://localhost:4567/");
URL url = new URL(baseUrl, "123/asd")
```

Or you can do this as a one-liner:

```
URL url = new URL(new URL(new URL("http://localhost:4567/"), "123/"), "asd");
```

#### Output

> http://localhost:4567/123/asd

Comment: I edited my answer. You were missing `/` after `123`.

Comment: I mean without trailing slashes anywhere. After all that it the idea not to worry about slashes when construct the URLs.

Comment: @George Yeah I got what you say. It's weird it doesn't work like that.

Comment: @George: I suppose, if the base `URL` was `http://host/path/index.html`, everyone would agree that resolving the relative URL `about.html` against it, should result in `http://host/path/about.html` rather than `http://host/path/index.html/about.html`. Since the rules do not care about whether the name is `index.html` vs `path` or `123` vs `asd`, what makes the difference? → the trailing slash (or the absence of it)…